# Допустимость применения сочетания слов

Tags: этимология

Применимо ли применение сочетания слов "Потребительский экстремизм" и вообще такого понятия. Сочетаются ли применяемые слова вместе и отражает ли словосочетание ту суть которую в нее пытаются вложить.

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас много новых оборотов в моде...
Наверное, и этот имеет право на жизнь.
Вопрос "отражает ли суть" - и разряда "на засыпку". 
Поскольку у  "применяемых вместе" слов есть только одна суть - та, которую вкладывают. Другой, объективной просто не существует. Вот когда сочетание будет зафиксировано в авторитетных источниках с определенным значением - и возникнет подозрение, что кто-то употребил его в ином смысле... Вот тогда вопрос будет обсуждаем. А пока не вижу ничего лучше чем принять оборот за данность.

Answer (score 1):

Вот что об этом думает Грамма.ру: "Не вполне понятно, на основании каких критериев оценивать словосочетание как «удачное», а тем более степень такой удачности. Если принимать во внимание отчетливые смысловые признаки и распространенность оборота, то очевидно, что его можно квалифицировать как лексическую единицу русского языка". Но, если учитывать, какой смысл вкладывается в это словосочетание, то я бы заменил слово "экстремизм" на другое, более близкое к тому понятию, которое вкладывается в это словосочетание.

Comment: Максимализм?

Answer (score 1):

А почему нет? Экстремизм – это идеология допустимости использования крайних мер, экстремумов социального поведения, для получения желаемого эффекта.
 «потребительский экстремизм» — стремление недобросовестных клиентов получить определенную выгоду и доход, манипулируя законодательством в корыстных целях.
  http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC

Примеры экстремизма:
http://www.rosbo.ru/articles.php?cat_id=25&id=105
    В магазине спорттоваров и одежды женщина средних лет покупает горно-лыжный костюм за восемьсот долларов в конце марта месяца, когда сезон подходит к завершению. Через две недели она возвращается в магазин с костюмом и прямо в торговом зале в присутствии других покупателей устраивает ‘разнос' продавцу товара, угрожая судом и публикациями в прессе. Покупательницу сопровождает её юрист, который поддакивает и все видом своим выражает готовность ‘навести порядок в этом заведении'. Суть претензий состоит в том, что данный костюм не имеет сертификата соответствия, а его место изготовления– вовсе не Италия, а Турция. Разве это не экстремизм? Такие случаи сплошь и рядом. Знакомый предприниматель рассказывал, что так покупают и сдают часто платья для выпускного вечера: купят очень дорогое, через 3 дня после выпускного приносят назад: что-то не понравилось, скандалят, грозят судом, он принимает, несёт убытки, зная, что "попал на деньги", но скандалить с клиентом будет дороже: "клиент всегда прав". Разве это не экстремизм? В словарях пишут: эстремизм ОБЫЧНО в политике, а вообще бывает и в быту, и в религии, и в экономике. Нормальное сочетание и отражает суть понятия - использование крайних мер, манипуляции с законом.

Comment: Может быть  и так, не спорю! А как вы думаете, не лучше ли здесь было бы употребить слово " беспредел"?

Comment: Может, и лучше, это по теме  насаждения иноязычных слов в р.языке, но сейчас речь не о том, а о лексической сочетаемости, с этой точки зрения здесь всё нормально.

Comment: Ну, может быть.....